# Enter ID Number to find in textfile

Tags: c++

I have this mini project of mine, the goal is to produce an output of this:

```
Enter ID Number:
ID NUMBER        Name           Course
201901           Andy Jones     BSN
201901           Eddie Bell     BSA
2 result(s) found
```

But instead, I got this output:

```
Enter ID Number: 201902
ID NUMBER        Name           Course
201902           Colt Bridges   BSCS
ID NUMBER        Name           Course
201902           Kenny Durant   BSCE
ID NUMBER        Name           Course
201902           Kobe Bean      BSIE
3 result(s) found
```

The ID number keeps on looping, 
and when I enter a number in the ID Number, like "20", all of the outputs will show, how can I make the program accept only the exact ID number. 
Here's my code below.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;
    int main() {
        int offset , count = 0;
        string line, IDnum, name, course, search ;
        ifstream StudentList;
        StudentList.open("StudentFile.txt");
        cout << "Enter ID Number: ";
        cin >> search;
        if (StudentList.is_open()) {
            while (!StudentList.eof())
            {
                getline(StudentList, line);
                while ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos)
                {       
                        cout << "ID NUMBER\t" << " Name\t\t" << "Course\n";
                        stringstream ss(line);
                        getline(ss, IDnum, ',');
                        getline(ss, name, ',');
                        getline(ss, course);
                        count++;
                        cout << IDnum << "\t\t" << name << "\t" << course << endl;
                        break;
                }

            }
            cout << count << " result(s) found\n";
            StudentList.close();
        }
        else {
            cout << "Could not open file";
        }

        StudentList.close();
        _getch;
    }
```

And here's my text file

```
201901,Andy Jones,BSN
201901,Eddie Bell,BSA
201902,Colt Bridges,BSCS
201902,Kenny Durant,BSCE
201902,Kobe Bean,BSIE
```

Comment: Why do multiple people have the same ID number?

Comment: it was just an example, but multiple people can't have the same ID number.

Comment: If you know ID is unique, then stop searching once you find it. In the example this obviously doesn't work, but if your real world data has unique IDs you can stop after you find the first one.

Comment: You're printing the column headers for each record found because the code to print the header is in your loop that looks for matching records.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find for the operation of find.

Comment: Move the line that prints the headers to before the loop. If you spend a little time learning to use the debugger, you can step through the code and see exactly what it's doing so you can  figure this sort of thing out yourself. And you should provide actual code and data, not made up stuff, so you don't make silly mistakes like giving multiple people the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you don't care about unique IDs and just deals with the issues you have mentioned.

To start with, your search criteria is "20" which is satisfied by any of those IDs.
Since your file is always ID,NAME,COURSE you can append "," to your ID like this:

```
cin >> search;
search += ",";
```

and for the example of "20" it will only succeed for an entry like:

> 20,Kobe Bean,BSIE

The other reason is that the line where your print the headers:

```
cout << "ID NUMBER\t" << " Name\t\t" << "Course\n";
```

is ***INSIDE*** your loop. Try placing it before the loop like this:

```
cout << "ID NUMBER\t" << " Name\t\t" << "Course\n";
while (!StudentList.eof())
{
    getline(StudentList, line);
    while ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos)
    {       
        stringstream ss(line);
        getline(ss, IDnum, ',');
        getline(ss, name, ',');
        getline(ss, course);
        count++;
        cout << IDnum << "\t\t" << name << "\t" << course << endl;
        break;
    }
}
cout << count << " result(s) found\n";
StudentList.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

> The ID number keeps on looping

It keeps on looping because of the inner `while loop` i.e it will do the output for **n-times**, where **n** is the number of results (or the total count of same IDs) Hence I just added if-else statement to prevent the multiple outputs of the column names. So when it's found for the first time the ID do the header output, else just output the values of those columns.
As for outputting all values with

> 20 as an input

I guess the problem is with `line.find()` function, It seems it detects the substring hence get a mistake.

It just my first thought, but as others guys mentioned in the comment section, maybe it's better to analyze the question Because ID is unique value and different users can't have the same ID

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int offset , count = 0;

    string line, IDnum, name, course, search ;
    ifstream StudentList;
    StudentList.open("StudentFile.txt");
    cout << "Enter ID Number: ";
    cin >> search;
    if (StudentList.is_open()) {
        while (!StudentList.eof())
        {
            getline(StudentList, line);
            while ((offset = line.find(search, 0)) != string::npos)
            {       
                    if(count == 0){
                    cout << "ID NUMBER\t" << " Name\t\t" << "Course\n";
                    stringstream ss(line);
                    getline(ss, IDnum, ',');
                    getline(ss, name, ',');
                    getline(ss, course);
                    count++;
                    cout << IDnum << "\t\t" << name << "\t" << course << endl;
                    break;
                } else {
                    stringstream ss(line);
                    getline(ss, IDnum, ',');
                    getline(ss, name, ',');
                    getline(ss, course);
                    count++;
                    cout << IDnum << "\t\t" << name << "\t" << course << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
        cout << count << " result(s) found\n";
        StudentList.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Could not open file";
    }

    StudentList.close();
    _getch;
}
```

Comment: This is not a useful answer, as it does not explain why the code you've posted should be used instead of what the poster has already. How is this poster (or anyone else who reads this question in the future) supposed to learn anything from an answer when you don't make any effort to provide anything that teaches them?